# What are the PostTypeId's in the 2011-12 data dump?

Tags: support, data-dump

I work on the data dump from December 2011, and I have encountered two things that I need to ask about.

First:

In the README, it says that the attribute `PostTypeId` can only be 1 for the questions and 2 for the answers, but I found that there are another possibilities (3, 4, 5, 6, and 7).
So what are they?

Second (it's more a remark):

I found that sometimes there isn't an answer corresponding to the question's AcceptedAnswerId.

Comment: Not all questions have accepted answers.

Comment: Some accepted answers may have been deleted, without a new answer being accepted

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can [query Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/69572) for the list of `PostTypeId` values:

```
Id Name                
-- ------------------- 
1  Question            
2  Answer              
3  Wiki                
4  TagWikiExcerpt      
5  TagWiki             
6  ModeratorNomination 
7  WikiPlaceholder     
8  PrivilegeWiki
```

Also check out [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-data-explorer), which has similar information (although the list of post types seems to be a bit out of date at the moment).

The README should also be updated, but the way the data dump is being distributed is changing, so I'm not sure what impact that will have on how this kind of information is made available.

> I found that sometimes there isn't an answer corresponding to the question's AcceptedAnswerId

The data dump does not contain deleted content, so presumably the corresponding answers were removed by the owner or through moderation. I guess the export process doesn't remove invalid `AcceptedAnswerId` values, but I'm not sure that there's necessarily a reason it should.